# How to retrieve function parameter types with flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How would I extract parameter types from a function in flow?

For example if I have:

```
export const myFunc = (p1: {a: boolean, b: string}, p2: boolean) => [a, b];
```

in one file, how would a second file import `myFunc` and extract and use the `p1` type without executing `myFunc`?

Something alone the lines of `typeof` but for function parameters instead.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Hi Meghan, I'm trying to somehow extract the function parameter type from a function instance.

Comment: javascript does not natively support type definitions, so currently there is no way to do this from within your code

Comment: @Meghan Why do you respond to a question you don't have any clue about? This is about Facebook's Flow type system! You ever heard about TypeScript? Same thing, but just types. Please inform yourself before you comment.

Comment: OP, issues similar to yours in Flow's Github issues list: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/854 and https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4672 -- at least as far as actually trying to extract the argument types is concerned. As the answer already mentions, it already works for return types, but not (easily) for arguments. For the record: This question becomes very relevant in the context of *generics*, when there is no known function because the function is the generic parameter to a parent type. Then the accepted answer cannot be used and extraction of argument types is a real need..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of the ways to accomplish this is to create a separate type for arguments in your function, like following:

```
export type myFuncP1Type = {a: boolean, b: string};
export type myFuncP2Type = boolean;
export const myFunc = (p1: myFuncP1Type, p2: myFuncP2Type) => [a, b];
```

It is possible to export types similarly as function and variable. In place, where the type of arguments needed, it will be needed to import `myFuncP1Type` and `myFuncP2Type` like the following:

```
import {type myFuncP1Type, type myFuncP2Type} from .... ;
```

Even though flow utility types has a helper that will allow obtaining type for the result of the function call ([check docs for $Call](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call)), I can't find any utility type that will return type of the function arguments, so look like creating separate types for arguments is the right to do this.